# Find outer join of 2 neo4j CQL queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I have 2 CQL queries:-

```
MATCH (OX:OrderX) 
MATCH (OXT:OrderXType) 
WHERE OX.OrderXTypeID=OXT.OrderXTypeID
AND OXT.SourceTypeID="1"  
RETURN OX.OrderXID,OX.IdentifierID;
```

and

```
MATCH (OX:OrderX)
MATCH (OXT:OrderXType)
WHERE OX.OrderXTypeID=OXT.OrderXTypeID
AND OXT.SourceTypeID="2"
RETURN OX.OrderXID,OX.IdentifierID;
```

With outputs as:-

```
╒═════════════╤═════════════════╕
│"OX.OrderXID"│"OX.IdentifierID"│
╞═════════════╪═════════════════╡
│"-2147483640"│"-2147483644"    │
├─────────────┼─────────────────┤
│"-2147483639"│"-2147483643"    │
└─────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

AND

```
╒═════════════╤═════════════════╕
│"OX.OrderXID"│"OX.IdentifierID"│
╞═════════════╪═════════════════╡
│"-2147483643"│"-2147483643"    │
├─────────────┼─────────────────┤
│"-2147483641"│"-2147483641"    │
├─────────────┼─────────────────┤
│"-2147483642"│"-2147483642"    │
└─────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

I want the outcome as outerjoin on OX.IdentifierID(s).

The preferred result is:-

"-2147483641","-2147483642","-2147483644"

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

You can use the APOC function [apoc.coll.disjunction](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/data-structures/collection-list-functions/#collection-list-functions) to get the disjunction of 2 input lists.

For example:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (x1:OrderX), (t1:OrderXType)
WHERE t1.SourceTypeID = "1" AND x1.OrderXTypeID = t1.OrderXTypeID
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT x1.IdentifierID) AS x1s
OPTIONAL MATCH (x2:OrderX), (t2:OrderXType)
WHERE t2.SourceTypeID = "2" AND x2.OrderXTypeID = t2.OrderXTypeID
RETURN apoc.coll.disjunction(x1s, COLLECT(DISTINCT x2.IdentifierID))
```

*NOTE: This example uses `DISTINCT` to minimize the size of the 2 lists passed to the APOC function. But that is really optional, since `apoc.coll.disjunction` will return a list with distinct values anyway.*

Comment: The above query appears to do a plain join for me with the output as:- "IdentifierID": "-2147483641", "IdentifierID": "-2147483642", "IdentifierID": "-2147483643" and "IdentifierID": "-2147483644". But I just want the outer joins of the two data sets as - ("-2147483641","-2147483642","-2147483644")

Comment: Can you please help me to tweak this Cypher? I am new to Cypher.

Comment: I tried this:- OPTIONAL MATCH (x1:OrderX), (t1:OrderXType)
WHERE t1.SourceTypeID = "1" AND x1.OrderXTypeID = t1.OrderXTypeID
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT x1) AS x1s
OPTIONAL MATCH (x2:OrderX), (t2:OrderXType)
WHERE t2.SourceTypeID = "2" AND x2.OrderXTypeID = t2.OrderXTypeID
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT x2) AS x2s
RETURN apoc.coll.disjunction(x1s.CoreIdentifierID, x2s.CoreIdentifierID)

Comment: But I'm not sure why it gives me the Variable `x1s` not defined error.

Comment: While when I try this way, it gives me empty data set:- OPTIONAL MATCH (x1:OrderX), (t1:OrderXType)
WHERE t1.SourceTypeID = "1" AND x1.OrderXTypeID = t1.OrderXTypeID
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT x1.CoreIdentifierID) AS x1s
OPTIONAL MATCH (x2:OrderX), (t2:OrderXType)
WHERE t2.SourceTypeID = "2" AND x2.OrderXTypeID = t2.OrderXTypeID
RETURN apoc.coll.disjunction(x1s, COLLECT(DISTINCT x2.CoreIdentifierID))

Comment: See my updated answer. According to your question, you should be using `IdentifierID` instead of `CoreIdentifierID`.

Comment: Thanks! By any chance do you have any idea how to invoke apoc module into python? I couldn't find any articles on how to use APOC in python program.

Comment: APOC *functions* and *procedures* are invocable using Cypher (and Cypher can be invoked via Python). *Procedures* are invoked using the [CALL](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call/#query-call) clause, and *functions* are invoked like any other Cypher function.